# python django scrapy return item to controller

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, scrapy

I need to do some short real-time scraping and return the resulted data in my Django REST controller.

trying to make use scrapy:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from . models import Product

class MysiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.something.com/browse?q=dfd',
    ]
    allowed_domains = ['something.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        items_list = Selector(response).xpath('//li[@itemprop="itemListElement"]')

        for value in items_list:
            item = Product()
            item['picture_url'] = value.xpath('img/@src').extract()[0]
            item['title'] = value.xpath('h2').text()
            item['price'] = value.xpath('p[contains(@class, "ad-price")]').text()
            yield item
```

**items model**

```
import scrapy


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    picture_url = scrapy.Field()
    published_date = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
```

according to Scrapy architecture, items will be returned to the `Item Pipeline` (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/topics/item-pipeline.html) which is used to store the data to DB/save to files and so on.

However i'm stuck with the question - how can i return the scraped items list through the Django REST APIview?

**Expected usage example:**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .service.mysite_spider import MysiteSpider

    class AggregatorView(APIView):
        mysite_spider = MysiteSpider()

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            self.mysite_spider.parse()

            return Response('good')
```

Comment: Django REST API view 's data should come from *http request*, not from scrapy directly, so you should save scrapy item to db or file, which django can read from when request coming.

Comment: Why does it have to come from `request` ? Why can't i just use some logic within controller?
I updated the topic now to show what i mean.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't actually test the integration with Django REST framework, but the following snippet would allow you to run a Spider from a python script, collecting the resulting items to handle them later.

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler, CrawlerProcess
from ... import MysiteSpider

items = []
def collect_items(item, response, spider):
    items.append(item)

crawler = Crawler(MysiteSpider)
crawler.signals.connect(collect_items, signals.item_scraped)

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(crawler)
process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished

# at this point, the "items" variable holds the scraped items
```

For the record, this works, but there might be better ways to do it :-)

Further reading:

- https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script
- https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html

Comment: Good answer, thank you. But when I tried something like that, I got an following error: ValueError: signal only works in main thread